# About the global planner

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,guys，good evening.I am am using `move_base` to navigate a little car.It works.But how can know which kind of global planner I am using？It seems that I didn't config this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262132/about-the-global-planner/) by [little_bob](https://answers.ros.org/users/30063/little_bob/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2017-05-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to http://wiki.ros.org/move_base#Parameters , the default planners are **navfn** for global planner and **base_local_planner** for the local planner

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2017-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [little_bob](https://answers.ros.org/users/30063/little_bob/) on 2017-05-19**:
thank you very much.